# Certificates and Trust in Windows - Updates or Installs the the complete CTL?

Tags: client-certificates, ctl

there is a debate at my work about how this works
https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows-server/identity/ad-cs/certificate-trust

Does this funcrtionality only update certificates that have been installed. or will it install all the certificates on the list
https://ccadb-public.secure.force.com/microsoft/IncludedCACertificateReportForMSFTCSV.